# zooming the page will reset the carousel

Tags: carousel, zooming, spartacus-storefront

Is there a way to avoid reset the carousel after the user zoom in/out the browser page?
I found pages with similar carousel and this behaviour doesn't happens.
Go to spartacus demo website https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/, in the carousel navigate to the next block of slide, then zooming the page, you should see the carousel reset to the first block of slides.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: hi @Rob I added the scenario, I can't add a video. If you follow the steps you will se the behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour of the `CarouselComponent` is expected. Its service depends on `window.resize` event to adjust the number of items on carousel page whenever the window got resized.

If you consider it as a bug, please create an issue in the [Spartacus GitHub repository](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues). Team will take your proposal into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way this can be handled.
In DOM, instead of using Spartacus's `activeSlide` variable for rendering the UI, use one tempVariable named say `tempActiveSlide`

Reassign the `tempActiveSlide` only if the items per slide are changing. This count will change whenever the window resizes and which is as per the functionality of `CarouselService`.
Ref - https://sap.github.io/spartacus/injectables/CarouselService.html#source

This way, the carousel on UI will only reset if the number of items per slide have changed. Otherwise it wont reset.

TS code:

```
tempActiveSlide;
itemsPerSlide = 0;

ngOnInit(): void {
      super.ngOnInit();
      this.tempActiveSlide = this.activeSlide;
      this.size$.subscribe((items) => {
        if (items !== this.itemsPerSlide) {
          this.itemsPerSlide = items;
          this.tempActiveSlide = this.activeSlide;
        }
      });
  }
```